# Naming CMake Targets by directory

Tags: cmake

I am new to CMake and am having a bit of trouble. Is it possible to name CMake targets according to the directory they were created in? For instance, I would like to write my libraries to a lib/ directory that would echo my source directory structure.

Imagine i have source directories dir1 and dir2, and both create a library libmylib.a  Normally CMake might complain about creating libraries/targets with the same name, but if the libraries were written to lib/dir1/libmylib.a and lib/dir2/libmylib.a then you could reference these targets as dir1/libmylib and dir2/libmylib in your CMakeLists.txt files (presumably) without conflict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CMake, logical library name can be totally decoupled from the name of the file produced by the target. There is no problem in having a `/` in your target names. You could add your libraries like this:

```
add_library(dir1/mylib STATIC source1 source2 ...)
set_property(TARGET dir1/mylib PROPERTY OUTPUT_NAME mylib)
```